# Не работает slideDown

Tags: jquery

Хотел, чтобы при полной загрузке страницы выезжало слово. При slideUp - работает, стоит slideDown написать (как и я хотел, чтобы выезжало) - то сразу не хочет работать.

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/Alexey995/3swzk4nd/1/][1]
```

Что не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А откуда бы оно выезжало, если оно уже отображается? Добавляйте `display: none;` на блок (в класс или стиль), тогда всё будет работать.

```js
$('document').ready(function () {
    $('.wodrd1').slideDown('slow');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="wodrd1" style="display: none;"><strong>MAKE</strong></p>
```